# Separating theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, inner-products

I have convex the set $C:=C(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of convex combinations of $x_i$'s. I know that there exists an $x_i$ such that $\Vert x_i \Vert > 0$ and $ 0 \notin \mathring{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i x_i : \lambda_i \in (0,1) \text{ and sum up to 1}\}$. I also know that \begin{align*} \exists y \in C \>\forall c \in \mathring{C} : \> \langle y , c \rangle > 0. \end{align*}  Now I am supposed to show that $\langle y , x_i \rangle > 0$ holds.

Can somebody give me a hint for this task?

Comment: I am a bit confused...you know that $\langle y,c \rangle >0$ for all $c \in C$? Yeah well, but $x_i$ itself is also in $C$, since I can write it as the convex combination $1 \times x_i$...so you're done?

Comment: @Luke, sorry a typo, I only know the inequality for all $ c \in \mathring{C}$. I will fix this, thanks.

Comment: All right, then it looks like some continuity argument. You should use that the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous.

Comment: @Luke I was thinking about the same. I know that for all the $x_j$ there exists $c_j ^{n}$ such that $ \lim c_j^{n} = x_j$; whence $\langle y , x_j \rangle \ge 0$. But I don't see why this inequality should be strict in the case that $\Vert x_i \Vert > 0$.

Comment: I may be missing something... The convex hull of a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^n$ always have an empty interior.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $\mathring{C}$ means, that the lambdas in the convex combination are all in $(0,1)$. I will add this in the post, thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question. It is confusing to have a proper answer and then a new released question inside the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The result seems to be wrong.**

Take the plane, i.e. $\mathbb R^2$ with $x_1 = (1,0)$ and $x_2=(0,1)$. You have $\Vert x_1 \Vert = 1 \neq 0$. Now $y = x_2$ belongs to $C(x_1,x_2)$ and $\langle y, c \rangle >0$ for all $c \in \mathring{C}(x_1,x_2)$. Also $0 \notin \mathring{C}(x_1,x_2)$.

However $\langle y , x_1 \rangle = \langle x_2, x_1 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the result hold if I choose a specific y, in particular $y := d(0,\mathring{C})$, where $d$ defines the distance?